# Event to capture the scroll of a datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have 2 questions:
1. What would be the event to capture the fact a scroll has taken place in a datagrid?
2. Does anyone have any suggestions on how one could disable the scroll of the datagrid when a user clicks a cell then drags out of the datagid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the `DataGrid`, but [here's the Class doc for the `DataGrid`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) which I was looking at.

It may be *helpful* to look at the `horizontalScrollPolicy` function.

Anyway, it doesn't look like there is a scroll event, so what I would do is capture an `Event.CHANGE` event on your scrollbar and look at the target's *properties* to find out more about the scroll position. eg

```
function scrollChangeHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace(event.target.percentage); // or whatever the property is.
}
scrollBar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, scrollChangeHandler);
```

Also, to kill an event you can `stopPropagation` on the event. eg

```
function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
myItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
```

Unfortunately, this info is only *part* of your answer, but at least that second tip will help a number of times down the road. Wish I knew more to help. **Good luck!**

Comment: scrollBar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, scrollChangeHandler);  What is the scrollBar object. How do I get it from datagrid? Never done that before. Thanks.

Comment: You can just use a component scrollbar. I believe it's available in flex and flash. Better yet, If you will get some source together with just a sample of this issue you're talking about I will be happy to take a look at it and get you some feedback.